# Rlwrap vi-movement-mode does not work with some programs

Tags: readline

With `rlwrap cat` or `rlwrap bash` I can use keybinding "jk" to exit from insert mode.

This does not work with `rlwrap ghci`. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rlwrap's not very useful with programs which already do (even rudimentary) line-editing.  According to its [readme](https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap):

> Commands that already use readline will always ask for (and get)
>   single keypresses, which makes rlwrapping them rather
>   pointless. However, if one uses the -a option, rlwrap will use its own
>   line editing and history. Unforunately, in this case, rlwrap cannot
>   detect whether  asks for a password. This can be remedied by
>   giving the password prompt (excluding trailing space and possibly the
>   first few letters) as an argument to the -a option.

You might get some use out of rlwrap using the **`-a`** option, as suggested.  The first sentence is a little too specific (other programs can ask for "single keypresses" than those using readline).

Comment: It is not the programs that ask for single keypresses for which using `rlwrap` without the `-a` option is pointless, but the programs that _always_ ask for single keypresses. You are right that `readline` is not the only input method that does so ([editline](https://github.com/troglobit/editline), [JLine](https://jline.github.io/) and the `zsh` line editor are other examples). I'll make that clearer in the manpage.